# Angular - anchor tag with routerlink url getting encoded multiple times for href attribute

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-routing, routerlink, angular-routerlink

```
<a [routerLink]="'/stacks/'+stack.stackId+'/modify'" (click)="onClickModifyStack(stack.stackId)">
```

I am using template array,

> Scenario: stack.stackId = 'Stack123/22' which I am encoding it with encodeURIComponent, It displays fine in routerlink but in href it encodes multiple times.

I have tried encoding it before assigning it routerlink, but still did not work.

Expected:[mainurl] /stacks/**Stack123%2F22**/modify

Currently I am getting - [mainurl] /stacks/**Stack123%252F22**/modify

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and the fix for me was to use the array syntax that would encode each path segment as mentioned here: https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink

So using your code, it would change to:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/stacks/', stack.stackId, '/modify']" (click)="onClickModifyStack(stack.stackId)">
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @thenninger is perfectly fine. You can also shift things to the TS:

```
      <a (click)="navigateToLink(link)">
        {{ link.text }}
      </a>
```

and then in your TS:

```
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateToLink(link: string): void {
    // in here you can play with the string and freely play with it, then pass it as a string[] to the .navigate()
    this.router.navigate([link], { fragment: link.fragment }).then();
  }
```